# .htaccess RewriteRule index

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

First of all I would like to apologize for my English.

I'm trying to make pretty URLs. Unfortunately I have little experience in this area. Now .htaccess file contents look like:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule index/(.*)/(.*)/ index.php?category=$1&page=$2
RewriteRule index/(.*)/(.*) index.php?category=$1&page=$2
RewriteRule index/(.*)/ index.php?category=$1
RewriteRule index/(.*) index.php?category=$1
RewriteRule index/ index.php
RewriteRule index index.php
```

It works. Rewriting a link like:

`site.com/index/department/workers`

to:

`site.com/index.php?category=department&page=workers`

So index.php can work with this link. If there is no "page" parameter then the third or fourth rule handles the link. And so on.

The problem is that in the address bar there is "index". I would like a link like

`site.com/department/workers` (without index)

Is this possible? Or someone can give me advice how can I rewrite the rules?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove index from the rewrite rules. just ensure that you account for requests that match real files e.g.:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)/(.+)/?$ index.php?category=$1&page=$2

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)/?$ index.php?category=$1
```

This will:

- Defined index.php as the index file
- rewrite requests of the form `/something/somethingelse/` to `index.php?category=something&page=somethingelse`
- rewrite requests of the form `/something/` to `index.php?category=something`

Note that you don't need two rules to account for ends-with-/ and doesnt-end-with-/ - you can account for that in a single rule. More information on setting up rewrite rules can be found in [the documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html).

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*)/(.*)/ index.php?category=$1&page=$2
RewriteRule (.*)/(.*) index.php?category=$1&page=$2
RewriteRule (.*)/ index.php?category=$1
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?category=$1
RewriteRule / index.php
```

Not sure if this is what you mean though.